# Converting Decimal to char* in C++ windows form application

Tags: visual-c++, windows-forms-designer, tinyxml

in my project I need to convert Deciml variable to char*; 
Coz I need to save the value that user entered in a numericupdown control in a xml output using tinyXML. the function that I am using for printing text in tinyXMl, take the char* parameter.

TiXmlText(char *);

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Decimal? Perhaps `int`? See `itoa()` in the C runtime, or

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(T num)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << num;
    return stream.str();
}
```

and call

```
TiXmlText(to_string(666).c_str());
```

Comment: Hi friend! thank you so much for your help; I think that the value type in numericupdown is Decimal; so I need to do so :); let me to check your way in my project :)